# How to add text to a file in python3

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say i have the following file,

dummy_file.txt(contents below)
first line
third line

how can i add a line to that file right in the middle so the end result is:

first line
second line
third line

I have looked into opening the file with the append option, however that adds the line to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard file methods don't support inserting into the middle of a file. You need to read the file, add your new data to the data that you read in, and then re-write the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("dummy_file.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines.insert(1, "second line\n")
    with open("dummy_file.txt", 'w') as output:
        output.writelines(lines)
```

So:

1. We open the file an read all the lines making a list.
2. We insert to the list the desired new line, using `\n` for a new line.
3. We open the file again but this time to write.
4. We write all the lines from the list.

But I wouldn't recommend this method, due it hight memory usage (if the file is big).

Comment: The question specifically mentions they tried the append option. They don't want to add to the end, they want to insert into the middle.